# RegEx for excluding a match with prefix

Tags: regex, regex-look-ahead

I first wanted to only match the first instance, but soon realized that is not possible. The tool I'm using only uses RegEx so I have no options as well.

Basically I got a text with HTML tags in it and I want to match the first paragraph's tags without the following tags.
For example out of this:

`<p>erkfoijwdocndoufhwroguh</p><p>pijgoijkuohuhogiougwtg</p><p>pijgoijkuohuhogiougwtg</p><p>pijgoijkuohuhogiougwtg</p>`

I want to match the first `<p></p>`
and nothing else.
So I figured I could exclude the tags that have a tag right next to them using negative lookahead. As in:

`(?!>)(<|<\/)p>`

But for some reason this still matches every `<p>` and `</p>` tag instead of leaving out those that have another tag before them. Any suggestions?

Edit to add: I only need to match the tags, not the text inside the tags. And lookbehind doesn't work with the tool I'm using. It seems that everything that works [here](https://regexr.com/53iom), works also in my tool.

Second edit: I solved my problem, but I'm leaving the question open since the solution wasn't an answer and this seems like an interesting question and I might bump into similiar problem in the future. Basically if someone figures out how I can refer to `<p>` that doesn't have a `>` before it but also include the first `</p>`, I'd like to hear it.

Comment: `(?s)(?<=^<p>).*?(?=</p>)` might do.

Comment: you need to use lookbehind instead of lookahead

Comment: Regular Expressions by default look for match from Left to right. So you can go with <p>.*?</p> and take the first match or go with Match option instead of matches (if you are using .net flavor)

Comment: What exactly is (?s) supposed to do? And it seems that the tool I'm using doesn't recognize lookbehind, but only lookahead. Also I only need to match the tags. Not the text inside them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure I understood what you are trying to achieve, would  this:

`^<p>.*?<\/p>`

Demo here: https://regex101.com/r/ZXgMPV/1

Comment: This does work for the most part. It's just that I don't want to match the text but I want to only match the tags and not the text.

Comment: I probably can tell you how to do it if you tell me what tool / programming language you are using and what is the final objective you want to achieve, but it's complicated not knowing it. For instance variable-length lookbehinds would allow a simple solution but are mostly not supported. So what tool are you using and what are you trying to do with those <p> and </p>?

Comment: I am using EasyCatalog (a plug-in for Adobe InDesign), and it purely uses RegEx as is when calling for it. I did actually solve my problem thanks to your answer, altough it wasn't accurately answer to my question. What I ended up doing was just adding brackets so it looked like this: `^(<p>).*?(</p>)` and then i just called for the groups. I wanted to use EasyCatalog's in built replace function to replace the first tags with something else for InDesign styles. It works now, but I'll leave the question open if more accurate answer shows up!

Comment: that's exactly what I was going to suggest (that you use groups), but I was not sure if the tool you were using allowed you to do it. Even if you get new solutions, I doubt they will be more straightforward than this one so you can be confident going forward using it!